# Halve scroll speed for UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, core-animation

For testing (and for screen captures) I use [`layer.speed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427647-speed) to slow down animations globally.

```
window.layer.speed = 0.5
```

Yet this only controls animations, I cannot control `UIScrollView` speeds. Is there any (either undocumented/private) way to **halve the deceleration speed of scroll views**?

> I'm aware of [`UIScrollView.decelerationRate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/decelerationrate), yet it seems only work with the `.normal` and `.fast` values. I'm interested in slowing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any value to `decelerationRate` using raw value initializer.

```
scrollView.decelerationRate = .init(rawValue: 0.998)
```

This won't work for paging `UIScrollView` instances. For that, you need to set the `pagingFriction` property.

```
scrollView.setValue(0.9422507685, forKey: "pagingFriction")
```

For content offset animations (e.g. animation after refresh).

```
scrollView.setValue(0.6, forKey: "contentOffsetAnimationDuration")
```

> Thanks to this awesome [iOS-Headers](https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers) repo.

UPDATE: The best thing is the swizzling for tweaking deceleration rate from a bounce. I can't make it fit into this answer, see [`UIScrollView+Extensions.swift`](https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/iOS.Blog.SwiftUI_Pull_to_Refresh/blob/main/SwiftUI_Pull_to_Refresh/Extensions/UIScrollView%2BExtensions.swift) for details.